# Translate variable text by json array dictonary

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build a text translator. I have the following script where the words that are found will be translated. Now I need to keep the words that are not found in the json array  to be kept in the translated text.

Is there an easier way to replace the special characters?
I have already my own json dictonary, like the one in the example, and that must not come from somwhere online or third party because it is very technical and the script has to work offline!

I like to have a function because the textes are variable.

```
var dictionary = [
{
dutch: "motor",
english: "motor"
},
{
dutch: "voeding",
english: "supply"
}
];

//Translate this from dutch to english  
var text = "12V motor voeding is laag.";

text = text.replace(",", " ,");  
text = text.replace(".", " .");  
textArray = text.split(" ");

for (a = 0; a < textArray.length; a++) {  
var textItem = compare(textArray[a]);  
}

function compare(word){  
for (i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {  
if (word == dictionary[i].dutch){  
var textTranslated = dictionary[i].english;  
document.write(textTranslated + " ");  
}
```

I am getting following result:

```
motor power supply is low
```

There are missing the  `12v` and the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function compare(word){  
    for (i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {  
        if (word == dictionary[i].dutch) {  
            var textTranslated = dictionary[i].english;  
            document.write(textTranslated + " ");
            return;
        }  
    }
    document.write(word + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KienHT, its working much better but i have more variable textes to translate.
Take a look at a part of my html script below.
To translate with the same function:

```
document.write(foutgebied);  
document.write(fout);  
document.write(oplossing);
```

Maby i need to edit the html script also?

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<hr>
<p>     
<b>Foutgebied: </b>
<script>
document.write(foutgebied);
</script>
<br><br>
<b>Klacht: </b><br>
<script>
document.write(fout);
</script>
<br><br>
<b>Oplossing:</b><br>
<script>
document.write(oplossing);
</script>
</p>
<hr>
</form>
```